# はじめてプログラムの学習(Python）をしていますが、何が原因のエラーなのかわかりません。教えてください。

Tags: python

以下のようなプログラムを入力したのですが、エラーとなります。原因を教えていただけると助かります。

```
seisu1='6',seisu2='7'
print('seisu1')
print(seisu1)
print('i am'+'Mike')
print(seisu1+seisu2)
```

表示されるエラーメッセージです

```
 File "<ipython-input-22-81d4dc9ecc93>", line 1
    seisu1='6',seisu2='7'
          ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Comment: 「学習」という事なので何らかのテキスト(教科書・参考書の類)やウェブ上の記事などを参照しているのではないかと思われるのですが、それには `seisu1='6',seisu2='7'` という書き方が載っているのでしょうか？ なお、一行で書きたいのであればカンマではなくセミコロンを使います。 `seisu1='6';seisu2='7'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1行の中で`,`を使って2つの文を書いているからです。

```
seisu1='6',seisu2='7'
```

Pythonでこういう書き方はしないはずですね。
このように2行に分ければ良いでしょう。

```
seisu1='6'
seisu2='7'
```

あるいはこういう風に書きたかったのかもしれませんが。

```
seisu1,seisu2='6','7'
```

こちらを参考に：
[Python 構文 代入文・空行・行継続・複数文・インデント](https://cercopes-z.com/Python/syntax-indentation-py.html)

---

ちなみに上記参考先の途中に @metropolis さんのコメントの書き方も書いてありました。
ちょっと気付かなかったですね。追記しておきます。

> - 複数文
>
>   - １行で記述可能な単純文は、セミコロン (;) で区切って継続することが可能
>   - セミコロン (;) は、コロン (:) より優先